# adt bundle on linux hangs while loading

Tags: eclipse, console, adt

I downloaded the latest ADT bundle:

adt-bundle-linux-x86_64.zip

But when I try to run eclipse it hangs while loading org.eclipse.ui.console and I have to then force quit.

I'm running fubuntu 2012.4 and have openJDK 1.7.0_06-icedtea

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I solved similar problem using [this](http://neerajsingh.blog.com/2011/10/08/installing-eclipse-helios-on-ubuntu-11-4-zip-file/). First I unpacked the zip, and I was doing all as in there. And in unzipped directory was /sdk subdirectory which was needed to Android SDK Tools for Eclipse.